# Foreach loop not able to print output to .csv

Tags: powershell

Very new with using Powershell. I saw this script as an example and after tweaking it to suit my needs I find that it works fine, but I am having trouble correctly send the output to a `csv` file.

It tells me that "An empty pipe element is not allowed". What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Server "company.com" -Properties * -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=ssc, OU=Groups, OU=Users… " | Sort-Object Name  

Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    Write-Host $G.Name 
    $G.Members
    Write-Host "-------------"

}| Export-CSV -path c:\temp\Test.csv
```

Comment: You can't pipe the output from a `foreach($this in $that){}` construct through `|`

Answer (score 0):

`foreach($this in $that){}` is a *language construct*, not a *cmdlet*.

You can't output from a language construct through a pipe (`|`).

You can *assign* the output from such a construct to a **variable**, and then pipe *that* to another cmdlet:

```
$Members = Foreach($G In $Groups)
{
    Write-Host $G.Name 
    $G.Members
    Write-Host "-------------"

}

$Members | Export-CSV -path c:\temp\Test.csv
```